# Exclude Cancelled items from Org Mode Agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

is there a straightforward way to exclude an item starting with

```
* CANCELLED
```

from the agenda?

it seems like there is probably an easy way to do this in the docs by setting a variable in init.el but I haven't found it.

thanks

Comment: looks like a custom view is the way to go? https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make CANCELLED one of your TODO states and make sure that it is one of the DONE states. The agenda does not show DONE states by default. For example, add [something like the following](https://orgmode.org/manual/Per_002dfile-keywords.html#Per_002dfile-keywords) to the top of the file:

```
#+TODO: TODO DELEGATED WAITING | CANCELLED DONE
```

Press `C-c C-c` on the above line to make sure Org knows about it (or close the file and reopen it). A heading in a TODO state (those to the left of the vertical bar) is potentially shown in the agenda; if it is in a DONE state (those to the right of the vertical bar), it will not be.

This also gives you the ability to change the TODO state using standard methods (`C-c C-t` in the file, `t` in the agenda).

To do the equivalent setup using `org-todo-keywords`, add something like this to your init file:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '("TODO" "DELEGATED" "WAITING" "|" "CANCELLED" "DONE"))
```

adding a stringified vertical bar at the appropriate place - see [TODO keywords as workflow states](https://orgmode.org/manual/Workflow-states.html#Workflow-states) in the Org mode manual.

There are two variables whose settings might affect the above: `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done` and `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done` affect some aspects of whether an item is shown in the agenda: if these variables are non-nil, then a scheduled (resp. deadline) item will *not* be shown in the agenda if it is in a DONE state, but if they are nil, it *will* be shown but only on the relevant date. I recommend that you set them to non-nil for now and revisit them later if necessary.

You should definitely read the [TODO](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-Items.html#TODO-Items) chapter of the Org mode manual.

Comment: thanks that was exactly the type of fix i was looking for. One question, is there an equivalent way to do that in init.el? I'm currently defining TODO states there with `(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "CANCELLED" "DONE")))`

Comment: Added the info to the answer.

Comment: ah thanks, `|` works across both

Comment: and just a note for answer completion that I rearranged the order to be `#+TODO: TODO DELEGATED WAITING | DONE CANCELLED` since hopefully I'm finishing more than I'm cancelling.

Comment: won't let me edit a single chracter but the parens should be closed in the `(setq)` line

Comment: Just saw your last comment - must have missed it when first posted, more than a year ago (!!): thanks for pointing it out! Fixed.

Comment: ha no worries, a year later I've massively benefited from getting this figured out so thank you.